# How can I check if --allow-file-access-from-files is enabled or not?

Tags: google-chrome, cmd

How can I check if `--allow-file-access-from-files` is enabled or not? Is there any command on cmd or a checkbox on chrome's configuration?

I followed the steps to enable `--allow-file-access-from-files` but I am not sure if I really did it. And after I finish my work, how can I disable it to prevent security issues?

Comment: Windows: run Chrome and run `wmic process where "CommandLine like '%chrome.exe%'" get CommandLine /Value | find /I /C "--allow-file-access-from-files"` would **1**. display  the count of lines containing the string **and 2**.  raise [`find`-related `errorlevel`](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html). Caution: use `'%chrome.exe%'` only from pure command line window; apply `'%%chrome.exe%%'` in a batch script. And how can you disable it? Just reverse the procedure (steps) to enable it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the flags that Chrome is currently using by visiting **chrome://version**

However, this flag is not safe. Depending on your use case, you should consider something like a local server using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` to serve your page for testing.