# Javascript working in Firefox, but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am testing the following javascript project:https://github.com/cwilso/AudioRecorder. When I try to run the same project demo from this link: https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html it works on both browsers. But, when I download the project from github and run it localy from my computer, it doesn't work on Chrome. It just freezes(no waveform and the record button doesn't work).

Comment: Yes, I will fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Google chrome has some javascript limitations when the webpage is not run from a webserver or localhost server.

I'm not sure that's the issue but I'm putting my bet on it.

You can try adding "-allow-file-access-from-files" to your chrome shortcut and see if that fixes the problem. If it does that means that audiorecorder only works properly on a localhost or webserver.

---

Above file access issue in chrome is what I ran into a long time ago with less.js

Comment: Was just about answer what you did. OP could could also try this if they have python installed on their machine http://stackoverflow.com/a/33905343/351366